# Cell format changing

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to change the format in Cell `B4` on every Worksheet except the first and last and did this:

```
Dim num As Integer
num = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To num - 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range(B4).NumberFormat = "00"
Next i
```

First I am checking number of worksheets I have and then going from Sheet to till one before last sheet, but i get an error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add quotation marks when defining range:

```
Dim num As Integer
num = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To num - 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("B4").NumberFormat = "00"
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you :) Will flag your answer in 6 minutes